# Python arithmetic subtraction of element from iterable keeping type

Tags: python, iterable

Let's say I have an iterable (it could be either tuple or a list). I want to subtract a value from the elements of this iterable and return the result in the same type as the input iterable. For example,

```
a=(10, 7)
b=3
```

a-b must result in the following **tuple**

```
(7, 4)
```

and if a=[10, 7], a-b must result in the following **list**

```
[7, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script to create a new `list`/`tuple`:

```
a = [10, 7]
b = 3

a = type(a)(v-b for v in a)
print(a)
```

Prints:

```
[7, 4]
```

---

For `a=(10, 7)` prints `(7, 4)`

Answer (score 0):

```
b=(10,4)
a=[10,4]
constant=3
res = type(b)(map(lambda i: i - constant, b))
resultant = type(a)(map(lambda i: i - constant, a))
```

this will work for both list tuple or any type

Answer (score 0):

is easy use list compression

```
#--List
b=3
res=[i-b for i in [10,4]]
print(res,type(res))
#--[7, 1] <class 'list'>
```

```
#--tuple
b=3
res=tuple([i-b for i in (10,4)])
print(res,type(res))
#(7, 1) <class 'tuple'>
```

just create a class and ask for the variable type a and use the two methods above and voila

Answer (score 0):

Although all given answers are correct, I found the following answer better because it works even if the input is not iterable:

```
import numpy as np

list_a=[[10,7], (10,7), 10]
b=3

for a in list_a:
    c = type(a)(np.subtract(a,b))
    print(c, type(c))
```

it returns

```
[7, 4] <class 'list'>
(7, 4) <class 'tuple'>
7 <class 'int'>
```